# java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: _PYSPARK_DRIVER_CALLBACK_HOST

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, pycharm

i'm using PyCharm 2019.1, and Python 3.7 (in Project Interpreter)
On PyCharm, i've added Pyspark 2.4.2

when i run the following code (to create a Spark DataFrame), i get error

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: _PYSPARK_DRIVER_CALLBACK_HOST
....
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

from the other SO issues, it seems that it is related to version mismatch,
question is how to resolve this

my $SPARK_HOME points to Apache Spark 2.2.0,
when i try to install 2.2.0 on Pycharm, it gives error

```
Collecting pyspark==2.2.0

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyspark==2.2.0 (from versions: 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.2.0.post0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3)
No matching distribution found for pyspark==2.2.0
```

Any ideas on how to fix this ?

CODE ->

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("CreatingDF").getOrCreate()

pandaDF = spark.createDataFrame(d)
print(pandaDF)
```

ERROR ->

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
19/05/06 23:21:45 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[main,5,main]
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: _PYSPARK_DRIVER_CALLBACK_HOST
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonGatewayServer$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcV$sp(PythonGatewayServer.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrExit(Utils.scala:1262)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonGatewayServer$.main(PythonGatewayServer.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonGatewayServer.main(PythonGatewayServer.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:755)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/karanalang/PycharmProjects/PythonFalcon/FalconIncremental/python_createDF2.py", line 28, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("CreatingDF").getOrCreate()
  File "/Users/karanalang/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 173, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "/Users/karanalang/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 367, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/Users/karanalang/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 133, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "/Users/karanalang/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 316, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "/Users/karanalang/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 46, in launch_gateway
    return _launch_gateway(conf)
  File "/Users/karanalang/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 108, in _launch_gateway
    raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

Comment: when i add pyspark 2.4.2 in Pycharm, where does it get instaled ? fyi. in PyCharm (Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Console -> PythonConsole.. i'm able to see environment variables pointing to Apache Spark 2.2.0 .. pointing it to pyspark 2.4.2 should solve the issue ?

Comment: any ideas on this ?

Comment: i downloaded pyspark 2.4.3, and the Spark version in pyspark 2.4.3 => spark 2.2.0            So, it seems i have the right Apache Spark version (i.e. the PySpark version & Apache Spark version are compatible). however, the error still persists. I changed the Python version to 2.7 and i still see the same issue. .. trying to debug further.

Comment: @giosans -  i'm having similar issues, have tried the fixes mentioned, but still facing issues. Any ideas on how to debug/fix this is really appreciated.

Comment: @hi-zir @ SCOTT McNEIL- Any ideas on how to debug/fix this is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yes.It's versioning issue.  Verify your python version on your command prompt/terminal. If default python version is 2.7 and pyCharm is pointing to python3.7 in it's interpreter then it should work.

mostly Anaconda3 and onwards cause this issue.